# Склонение фамилии Головаха

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли фамилия *Головаха (Ольга)*?

Answer (score 2):

Склоняется по типу существительного.  Причем как мужская, так и женская. Головаха, у Головахи, к Головахе, Головаху,с Головахой,о Головахе.

Answer (score 0):

Мужские и женские фамилии славянского происхождения *на -а ударное склоняются* (с Григорием Сковородой).
  У вас - Головаха.  Фамилия явно славянского происхождения, но неударное -а. Возникают сомнения: склоняется ли?

"Нестандартные русские и нерусские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на -а, -я, склоняются. 
    Фамилии мужская и женская:

И.  Зима,   Зоя,    Варга
Р.  Зимы,   Зои,    Варги
Д.  Зиме,   Зое,    Варге
В.  Зиму,   Зою,    Варгу
Т.  Зимой,  Зоей,   Варгой
П.  о Зиме, о Зое,   о Варге

**Множественное число фамилий во всех падежах: Зима, Зоя, Варга**" ([www.gramma.ru](http://www.gramma.ru) *Культура письменной речи)*
Если считать фамилию Головаха нестандартной, то она склоняется.
P.S.*Цитата из статьи **"Склонение фамилий" на ГРАМОТА.РУ**:*
13.1.11. Наиболее сложную картину представляют собой фамилии с конечным а. В отличие от предыдущих случаев, здесь существенное значение имеет, следует ли а после гласной или после согласной, падает ли на эту гласную ударение и (в определенных случаях) какого происхождения фамилия.

Все фамилии, **кончающиеся на а**, **которому предшествуют гласные** (чаще всего у или и), **несклоняемы**: Галуа, Моруа, Делакруа, Моравиа, Эриа, Эредиа, Гулиа.

Все фамилии, кончающиеся на **неударное а после согласных**, склоняются по первому склонению: Рибера — Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой, Сенека — Сенеки и т.д.; так же склоняются Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка, Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Нагнибеда, Окуджава и др. Все такие фамилии, независимо от происхождения, являются морфологически членимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них выделяется окончание -а.
Среди фамилий с ударным á после согласных есть как морфологически членимые, так и нечленимые, т. е. несклоняемые.
Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения: Дюма, Тома, Дега, Люка, Ферма, Гамарра, Петипа и др.
Фамилии иного происхождения (славянские, из восточных языков) склоняются по первому склонению, т. е. в них вычленяется ударное окончание -а: Митта — Митты, Митте, Митту, Миттой; сюда относятся: Сковорода, Кочерга, Кваша, Цадаса, Хамза и др.
О ***множественном*** числе и ***нестандартных*** фамилиях есть упоминания в статье **"Правила изменения имён и фамилий. Склонение"  ([www.gramma.ru/Культура](http://www.gramma.ru/Культура) письменной речи - СПРАВОЧНЫЙ РАЗДЕЛ.**)

Comment: Конечно, нестандартная. Стандартная на -а - типа Иванова...

Comment: Насколько я знаю, фамилии у нас принято делить на группы по последним буквам: на -ова, на -ина, на -ых и т.д.  Иванова - это фамилия на  -ова. На -а: Стрига, Ворона, Река. Похоже, они и в самом деле все нестандартные))).

Answer (score 0):

Не надо ничего делить. 
И нет никаких на лазеек, ни стандартных фамилий... Все предельно просто. Вы, видимо, неправильно поняли изложенное на gramma.
В отношении фамилий на -а там сказано (по памяти - не могу найти это место) следующее:

~1. **Фамилии на -а неударное склоняются все**. Без изьятий.  
~2. **Фамилии на -а ударное склоняются (по [gramma.ru](http://gramma.ru)) в зависимости от происхождения**. Славянские склоняются, неславянские - нет.

На самом деле однозначно не склоняются только французские фамилии на -а (естественно, ударное): Золя, Дега и т.д. Остальные (нефранцузские) неславянские фамилии испытывают колебания. До недавнего времени нормативным считалось их склонение.

В отношении  множественного числа - вообще не понял. Выбор варианта обычно определяется контекстом и иситорическими традициями, никакой логикой не объясняется даже в простых случаях. Cсравните: братья Гримм, но братья Гонкуры; Барак и Мишель Обама, но Малия и Саша Обамы (последние примеры - из газет).

Вот [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_482) - более полно.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, добавляю к  ответу необходимые цитаты и ссылки. "Лазейку" убираю).